# Build failure when upgrading Unity 2020.03 -> 2022.03 related to duplicate Google Play Games

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have just updated from unity 2020.03.47 to 2022.03.06 and facing a build error

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
D:\Working Area\Project001\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\launcher\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-41 Error:
Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.games.unityVersion@value value=(\u0030.10.14) from [:unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-41
is also present at [:unityLibrary:GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-41 value=(\u0030.10.12).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:44 to override.

I am using GPGS Plugin version 0.10.12 and want to keep it.

It all worked ok on the 2020 version but I am stuck with the build for 2022. Can you please advise what to do? (with stupid-proof instructions if possible)

I tried building the app but it failed.

Comment: the package look like duplicated. In new version of android resolver. Unity will auto create lib for android project. backup old lib first, and delete the it in the plugin folder. And try again

Comment: thanks @sycoi001, I followed your tips and I managed to solve the issue:
1. deleted /Library/Bee folder
2. deleted /Assets/Plugins/Android folder
-re imported my used plugins